# Result subquery for multiples values - SQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I am getting feedback from `SUBQUERY` when I add more than one customer name to `QUERY`, but if you enter only one value, even using the `IN` condition, `QUERY` works perfectly

**QUERY FAILED**

```
SELECT "CUSTOMER",
    ( ( ( ( CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) ) - (
        SELECT
            (CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT))
        FROM
            public.tbl_metrics
        WHERE
            "CUSTOMER" IN (
                'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3'
            )
            AND "STATUS" = 'NOT_TESTED'
        GROUP BY
            "STATUS",
            "CUSTOMER"
    ) ) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) ) * 100) as "PERCENT", count("STATUS") as "OK"
FROM
    public.tbl_metrics
WHERE
    "CUSTOMER" IN (
        'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3'
    )
    AND "STATUS" = 'NOK'
GROUP BY
    "STATUS",
    "CUSTOMER"
```

**QUERY SUCCEED**

```
SELECT "CUSTOMER",
    ( ( ( ( CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) ) - (
        SELECT
            (CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT))
        FROM
            public.tbl_metrics
        WHERE
            "CUSTOMER" IN (
                'CLIENT1'
            )
            AND "STATUS" = 'NOT_TESTED'
        GROUP BY
            "STATUS",
            "CUSTOMER"
    ) ) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) ) * 100) as "PERCENT", count("STATUS") as "OK"
FROM
    public.tbl_metrics
WHERE
    "CUSTOMER" IN (
        'CLIENT1'
    )
    AND "STATUS" = 'NOK'
GROUP BY
    "STATUS",
    "CUSTOMER"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really clear what "getting feedback" means? I'd guess that your subquery is returning more than one row (because with the inner query grouping multiple customers = multiple results).

I'd recommend starting with a simpler version, get that working, and then add the extra calculations (i.e. percentages). Here is a rough starter query (not guaranteeing that this will work as I don't have access to your table and am taking a guess that this is what you wish to accomplish).

```
SELECT met."CUSTOMER",
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM
            public.tbl_metrics innerMet
        WHERE
            innerMet."CUSTOMER"= met."CUSTOMER"
            AND "STATUS" = 'NOT_TESTED'
    ) as "NOT_TESTED", count("STATUS") as "OK"
FROM
    public.tbl_metrics met
WHERE
    met."CUSTOMER" IN (
        'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3'
    )
    AND met."STATUS" = 'NOK'
GROUP BY
    met."STATUS",
    met."CUSTOMER"
```

Comment: Ammended answer using name "CUSTOMER". Note: I'd recommend not using double quotes; this forces postgres to treat the names as being case sensitive (without the quotes it automatically converts table names to lower case).

Comment: one thing to be aware of; the example will only return records where the customer has at least one 'NOK' status (so you will never get a 0 in the 'OK' column).

Answer (score 1):

If your subquery returns more than one result, this query will display an error, because you do a substraction which requires a single row result...
It seems your subquery returns at least 2 rows when you ask for multiple customers